# tailwind-rn tailwind function returns empty object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tailwind-css

I was trying to set up tailwind-rn in my project, but it seems impossible. The documentation says you should use `yarn add tailwind-rn` to install, then `npx setup-tailwind-rn` to set it up. This is a code example on the github page:

```
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, View, Text} from 'react-native';
import {useTailwind} from 'tailwind-rn';

const Hello = () => {
    const tailwind = useTailwind();

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={tailwind('h-full')}>
            <View style={tailwind('pt-12 items-center')}>
                <View style={tailwind('bg-blue-200 px-3 py-1 rounded-full')}>
                    <Text style={tailwind('text-blue-800 font-semibold')}>
                        Hello Tailwind
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

export default Hello;
```

My code looks like this:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {useTailwind} from 'tailwind-rn';

export default function App() {

  const tailwind = useTailwind();

  return (
    <View style={tailwind('text-white')}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

The code does not throw any error, but simply produces nothing. I also checked the value of `tailwind('text-white')`, which seems to be just an empty object. Why does that not work?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your dependencies ***(package.json)***

```
                "tailwind-react-native-classnames": "^1.5.1",
```

and ***Import*** it in your project page like this,

```
               import tw from "tailwind-react-native-classnames";
```

Finally use the ***tailwind*** styles like this,

```
                              style={tw`flex-1`}       
              <View style={[tw`bg-gray-200`, { height: 0.6 }]} />
```

And finally your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the root of your app into TailwindProvider:

```
   <TailwindProvider utilities={utilities}>
     <MyComponent/>
   </TailwindProvider>
```